# UriMapper and rewritten URI issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Sorry for the lame question title, it's hard to describe the problem in one sentence. The problem is as follows:

I need to make sure user has accepted license agreement before he can start using the app. My idea is to use UriMapper, which will check if user has accepted agreement before, and if not, redirect him or her to the license agreement page.

```
public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        if(!settingsStorage.IsLicenseAgreementAccepted)
            return LicenseAgreementPage;
        return uri;
    }
```

However, on the license agreement page, if I override OnNavigatedTo, I see that the navigation URI is not current page's URI, but rather the non-mapped URI, e.g. address of my main page. Therefore, when I try to navigate to that main page, nothing happens, since navigation service think I'm already there.

```
public partial class LicenseAgreementPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e); // somehow e.Uri equals to /MainPage.xaml, instead of /LicenseAgreementPage.xaml
    }
}
```

So how to overcome this? Is the UriMapper not applicable here? Or is there some workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like this should be doable... weird you are not getting the correct URI, maybe take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx) it describes a similar approach to launch a specific page of a wp8 app based on the given URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem where some pages required the user to log on. If the user tried to go to a page requiring login, they were redirected to a login page and then sent back. Maybe you can use the same strategy?

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (Requirelogin && !CurrentAppManager.IsUserLoggedIn)
        { 

           // Transfer URI to the login page and save it, after successful login, 
           // the login page navigate back to the stored URI
            ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(new Uri("Login?" + Helpers.URI + "=" + e.Uri.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
        }

        // if the user has just come from Login
        // remove it from the stack so they dont hit when pressing back
        var entry = NavigationService.BackStack.FirstOrDefault();

        if (entry != null && entry.Source.OriginalString.Contains("Login"))
        {
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This means I need to modify all the pages, which could potentially be the first after an app launch (there could be separate because of deep linking. Not an ideal solution, but thanks for sharing anyway.

Comment: Yes, but I did this by having all my pages inherit from a base page that could handle this kind of issues.